# How can I unlink a duplicate object? Object - Relations - Make single user - object and data is not working?

Tags: duplicate

I am having an issue with unlinking original object and a duplicate object that does not have a material but has a bevel feature. I’ve tried selecting *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data* which is not working and I’ve also tried *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings*. The keys I’ve used is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Hello, if you've done a Shift D, the duplication is not linked, it's a different mesh, so unlinking won't do anything special. Also, what are you trying to do exactly with that duplication that you can't do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the mesh information is linked between them (This would be alt+D, not shift+D tho) a '2' would show here on the Object Data tab:
[image]

Meaning there's 2 objects sharing that mesh information.
If you click it it will separate it will create a new one for the object that you have selected